# How to know current active installation profile like standard/minimal etc. on existing drupal site?

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

I have installed minimal installation profile. Is there any entry in database where profile name is mentioned, current active profile.

I wanna get the profile name which is get installed in existing site.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to `/admin/reports/status`, under Drupal if you see something written after Drupal version, that's your installation profile. If there is nothing, that means it is Standard profile.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the function [drupal_get_profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_profile/8.1.x)

> Gets the name of the currently active installation profile.
>
> When this function is called during Drupal's initial installation process, the name of the profile that's about to be installed is stored in the global installation state. At all other times, the "install_profile" setting will be available in settings.php.

Comment: where does the profile name stored in database? In which table I can find profile name?

Comment: It doesn't @SugandhKhanna, it's added to settings.php during installation. It's never saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily get it with the config api.

```
$profile = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->get('core.extension')->get('profile');
```

In the database, it is in the **config** table, serialized under the **core.extension** entry.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve Drupal distribution and installation profile information.

```
$profile = drupal_get_profile();
  $profile_info = system_get_info('module', $profile) + array(
    'distribution_name' => 'Drupal',
    'version' => VERSION,
  );
```

More information visit [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1170362)

Comment: where does the profile name stored in database? In which table I can find profile name?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Drush:

```bash
drush core-status | grep profile
```

Sample output:

```
Install profile  : demo_umami
```